# Gaps in consecutive periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table:

| user_id | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 2022-05-31 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-06-30 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-07-31 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-09-31 |

I need to get a table grouped by user_id and type and validity period. The main difficulty is that the periods may not be consecutive (they have more than 1 month distance between each other):

Otput should be:

| user_id | type | start_month | end_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 2022-05 | 2022-05 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-06 | 2022-07 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-09 | 2022-09 |

Comment: What's the criteria? When two periods are *consecutive*?

Comment: @lemon month sequence

Comment: Month sequence is not informative enough. Your example output has a start_dt and end_dt. Do you use one for ordering (sequence) and not the other? If so, which one?

Comment: @majixin i edited the Otput. Ordering by year and month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another approach, we could use the `row_number` function as the following:

```
select user_id, type, min(date_) start_month, max(date_) end_month
from(
  select *,
    date_ - interval '1 month' * row_number() over (partition by user_id, type order by date_) grp
  from table_name
) t
group by user_id, type, to_char(grp, 'YYYY-MM')
order by user_id, type, start_month
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EkR_5MdL)

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical gaps-and-island problem, where you need to build a more refined partitioning. In order to do that you:

- create a flag to understand when to change partition
- compute a running sum on the flag to create your actual partitions
- apply the aggregation

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN LEAD(date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, type ORDER BY date) > date + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS changepart
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(changepart) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, type ORDER BY date) AS parts
    FROM cte
)
SELECT user_id, 
       type, 
       MIN(date) AS start_dt,
       MAX(date) AS end_dt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY user_id,
         type, 
         parts
```

**Output**:

| user_id | type | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 2022-05-31 | 2022-05-31 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-06-30 | 2022-07-31 |
| 1 | usual | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-30 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ar58wPYhj1Zcr7n4cN5VaZ/0).

**Note**: You can't have year and month only dates. A date is always composed of a year, a month and a day. At best, your "*start_dt*" and "*end_dt*" can be transposed to the first day of that month, using `DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', your_date)`.